# Binding to RadioButtons IsChecked gets cleared after uncheking

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a radioButton group and each Button is binded to an Enum property

```
<RadioButton Name="rbFixedDiscount" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DiscountType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter},ConverterParameter=Fixed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >Fixed:</RadioButton>

<RadioButton Name="rbPercentDiscount" Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DiscountType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter},ConverterParameter=Percent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Percent:</RadioButton>

<RadioButton Name="rbFreeNightsDiscount" Grid.Row="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DiscountType, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter},ConverterParameter=FreeNights, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Free Nights:</RadioButton>
```

Whenever I click back and forth in the UI the property behind only gets updated when I click a new RB, If I click one of the buttons back ( so I make it Checked -> Unchecked -> Checked) the property behind the binding doesn't refresh, it's binding has been cleared I think it is because the  ClearValue()  gets called when unchecking and Item.
Anyway I can keep the binding alive while clicking back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known and annoying bug](https://sharpinsights.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/readiobutton-ischecked-binding-problem-conclusions/) with radio buttons.  Fortunately, there are a few workarounds, here are a few that I've seen:

1. Restyle a listbox as a radio button and use that instead.
2. Declare the binding in a control template.  ([link](https://sharpinsights.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/readiobutton-ischecked-binding-problem-conclusions/))
3. Put each radio button in a different group and control their checked/unchecked property through a value converter.  ([link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116211246/http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2008/10/17/125901.aspx))

Hopefully one of those solutions will work for you!

Comment: Seems to be fixed in .NET 4.0.